# Pass a function inside another function React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I ve got the following component which renders an audio player. The meditationList function gives me the location of the file that I want to play dynamically, and audio function is the functionality of player.

What I want to do is to pass the meditation list return on track player url

Thank you

```
export default class Player extends React.Component<Props> {
  meditationList = () => {
    const adress = this.props.route.params;

    return JSON.stringify(adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress);
  };
  audio = () => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
      // Adds a track to the queue

      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: 'trackId',
        url: this.require(meditationList()),
        title: 'Track Title',
        artist: 'Track Artist',
      });

      let trackId = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();

      // Starts playing it
      TrackPlayer.play();
    });
  };

  pause = () => {
    TrackPlayer.pause();
  };

  stop = () => {
    TrackPlayer.stop();
  };




  render() {
    return (
     ....)}}}
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HIpy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please change your code as below

1. Remove the duplicate function
2. Change `url: require('../../../assets/track.mp3')` to `url: this.require(meditationList()),`

---

```
export default class Player extends React.Component<Props> {
  meditationList = () => {
    const adress = this.props.route.params;
    return JSON.stringify(adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress);
  };

  audio = () => {
    TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async () => {
      // Adds a track to the queue

      await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: 'trackId',
        url: require(this.meditationList()),
        title: 'Track Title',
        artist: 'Track Artist',
      });

      let trackId = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();

      // Starts playing it
      TrackPlayer.play();
    });
  };

 pause = () => {
    TrackPlayer.pause();
  };

  stop = () => {
    TrackPlayer.stop();
  };

  render() {
    return (
     ....)}}}
```

Comment: hi thank you for your reply, I followed your instructions and i am getting the following warning : possible unhandled promise rejection, Reference Error can't find variable:meditaitonList_called

Comment: The thing is I've consoled log the function is giving me a path if I put that path in URL is working, however, if a put the function in url is not working.

Comment: Hi could you put the console log of the `adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress` and value of `adress ` as well

Comment: console.log(adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress) is equal with "../../assets/track.mp3" if i put this value by itselfs in url it works and adress type of is object

Comment: Hence it already a string there is no need to treat it as a JSON so change `return JSON.stringify(adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress);` to `return adress.meditation.meditationPlayerAdress;`

Comment: hi so i modified the return but i am getting the "unhandeled promise rejection, can't find variable meditation list"

Comment: ```` Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 13):
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: meditationList```